# unique holomorphic solution

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Show that for any locally defined holomorphic function $g$ at $0$ $\in \mathbb{C}$, there is a unique holomorphic solution $f$ of the equation $f'=g \circ f$ on $D(0,r)$ with $f(0)=0$ for any sufficiently small $r>0$.

Comment: You posted a number of questions without showing any work or responding to those who answered. What have you tried here?

Comment: What I have tried:

$\int \frac{df}{g(f)} = \int dz$. So I let $y=f(z)$ and hence what I have obtained from the equation will be $\int \frac{dy}{g(y)} = z$ . I am not sure how to proceed from here.